# Javascript object member function: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ," (Chromium)

Tags: javascript, chromium

I have this code block:

```
var Function1 = function (argument1) {
    // ...
};

var Function2 = function (argument2) {
    // ...
};

var MyObject = { "somekey": {}, Function1, Function2 };
```

This works great in every Windows/IOS browser.

On Android when `MyObject` is instantiated in Chromium it throws `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"`. I suspect my syntax is a bit loose somewhere. Why is `,` reported as out of place?

Comment: what is the type of ```MyObject```? it is neither map or array.

Comment: This is short-hand object property syntax where `Function1` is the short-hand for `Function1: Function1`. Only supported in ES6.

Comment: @DegenSharew It’s an object.

Comment: http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, you need an older syntax, pre ES6, with key/value pairs.

```
var MyObject = { somekey: {}, Function1: Function1, Function2: Function2 };
```